# Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

I am trying to record and perfom manual test with MTM.  Has anyone recorded SSN number or adding m date manually in the application with MTM,  having AJax MASK control.
I am unable to playback action once recorded my action fails.  looking for suggestion

Comment: Action recordings depend a lot on the way the app was coded. It may be that it can't find the field. What is the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

If you're entering data into a text field, you need to make sure you click off the field (click somewhere or hit the tab key) BEFORE you complete that step. If you don't do that, it won't be able to find the text control.

For instance, if you have a test step like

1) Enter Username

You need to

1. enter the username into the appropriate field
2. hit the tab key
3. mark the step as completed